# Authorization with htaccess

Tags: python, url, post, authentication

I'm using python and I have to login at some site, which asks for password. For asking it uses .htaccess like:

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Authorize please"
require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/home/*/admin/passwd"
```

So, when loading this page I'm getting browser's modal input window. How can I insert data with python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [these examples](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml).